# Document Approval Workflow - SharePoint Designer 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow

I've spent many days scouring the internet for something that will help me, but I'm not finding what I'm looking for. I need a document approval workflow for SharePoint 2013, with what would be conditional approvals, I think?

First off, I have the following columns in my doc library: Name, Modified, Modified By, Requester (Person or Group column type), Needs Invitation (Yes/No check box).

I need a workflow that sends the document (when uploaded) to Person X for approval. If Person X rejects, it routes back to who uploaded the doc (Modified By). If Person X approves and the Needs Invitation box is set to No, the workflow ends and an email is sent to the Requestor indicating the document is approved. If Person X approves and the Needs Invitation box is set to Yes, an email is sent to Person Y indicating that the document is approved and an invitation is needed. I also would like a direct link to the document to be included in the email (not to the doc library) if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Open up SharePoint Designer.

Create a new Workflow for that Document Library. Set the workflow to Start automatically on new item create.

Inside workflow

1. Drop activity `Start Approval Process`. Here choose `Person X`.

You can modify `Approval Process`. Then modify how overall Task Process. Here you can add `Send Email` activity in case of Approval or Reject.